# Передача данных между окнами в браузере javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть 3 вкладки A, B, C, в каждой разные сайты. Нужно с сайтов B и C передать данные на вкладку А. Как я понял localstorage и cookie не подходят в виду того что без хитроумных манипуляций на другой домен оттуда инфу не передашь. postmessage не могу найти примера где бы показывали как передавать не по фрейму, можно ли такой примерчик? Или если есть, более простой способ это сделать.

Comment: 1. Все три сайта (домена) – ваши (вы можете любой скрипт разместить на всех)? 2. вкладки открываются скриптом, или вручную? - Чтобы их "адресовать" надо знать имя окна, т.е. создать его скриптом. Основной вариант – [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: Сайты не мои. Вкладки открываются вручную. А нельзя ли как-то получить список открытых окон?

Comment: Еще можно посмотреть в сторону расширений (экстеншенов) для браузера

Answer (score 1):

В JavaScript запрещены любые кроссдоменные манипуляции с данными, обойти можно только через специальное api для сайта.

Используйте специальные библиотеки php, например curl или unit test(scriptable browser).

Answer (score 1):

Если сайты **B** и **C** открывались из вкладки **A**, то можно кроссдоменно общаться через `opener.postMessage('бла-бла-бла', '*')`

Хотя сам объект **`opener`** недоступен при кроссбраузерном общении, но *эта* его функция - доступна (проверено в Chrome 77.0.3833.0 (Official Build) dev (64-bit) и FireFox 60.8.0esr (64-bit))!